Getting "No AWS accounts are available to you" when using aws configure sso
I set up a user in AWS IAM Identity Center. When I run aws configure sso, I enter the session name, start url, region, and registration scope (it defaulted to sso:account:access so I just use that) and then I log in the browser with my user login, and after login success, I get No AWS accounts are available to you.
I notice after login, a file is created at /Users/[user]/.aws/sso/cache
I am trying to authenticate so that I can use aws ecr get-login-password to push a docker file to aws container registry.
UPDATE:
Watching this video cleared up how to manage accounts in IAM Identity Center:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_KhrGFV_Npw
Now I can successfully log in using aws configure sso from the command line.
However, after logging in, when I try to run this command to push a container to the AWS container registry:
aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin [id].dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
I am getting this error:
Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running aws configure.

Can you add how your .aws/config is configured (reduct sensitive info)?

Also, did aws configure sso asked you to select an account?

Here is my .aws/config and I also edited my question above because I got past the sso login issue...
[profile AdministratorAccess-xxxxxxxxx]
sso_session = my-sso
sso_account_id = xxxxxxxxx
sso_role_name = AdministratorAccess
[sso-session my-sso]
sso_start_url = https://xxxxxxxx.awsapps.com/start
sso_region = us-east-1
sso_registration_scopes = sso:account:access

Yes, once I got things set up correctly in IAM Identity Center, when I ran aws configure sso, it then auto-selected an account because it was the only account.

That video is good for explaining identity centre and showing how to get the access keys to just do aws configure but it doesnt fix the: no accounts are available to you. Recent experience has taught me overzealous stackoverflow admins, especially aws related will close all new questions on same post and redirect users to existing posts. Please change your heading.

When you setup your aws cli sso profile aws configure sso, it will ask you the following details:
▶ aws configure sso
SSO session name (Recommended): mysso
SSO start URL [None]: <start_url>
SSO region [None]: <aws_region>
SSO registration scopes [sso:account:access]: <>

Attempting to automatically open the SSO authorization page in your default browser.
If the browser does not open or you wish to use a different device to authorize this request, open the following URL:
https://device.sso.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/
Then enter the code: xxxxxxxx

Once you login, it will ask the the account and role to use:
There are # AWS accounts available to you.
<Select account>
Using the account ID 1234567890
The only role available to you is: AdministratorAccess
Using the role name "AdministratorAccess"

CLI default client Region [<aws_region>]:
CLI default output format [json]:
CLI profile name [AdministratorAccess-123456789]:

And it will tell you how to use the profile created:
To use this profile, specify the profile name using --profile, as shown:
aws s3 ls --profile AdministratorAccess-123456789

So in your case:
# .aws/config

[sso-session my-sso] 
sso_start_url = xxxxxxxx.awsapps.com/start 
sso_region = us-east-1 
sso_registration_scopes = sso:account:access

[profile AdministratorAccess-xxxxxxxxx] 
sso_session = my-sso 
sso_account_id = xxxxxxxxx 
sso_role_name = AdministratorAccess 


You need to run your aws command with --profile AdministratorAccess-xxxxxxxxx
aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 --profile AdministratorAccess-xxxxxxxxx | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin [id].dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com


it doesn't show anything except:
No AWS accounts are available to you.
After returning from the browser.

one possible solution that this error occurs is if you don't have an IAM user with proper access and access given to IAM identity center user "amplify-admin" created via
  printf "\n\nStart session url: https://$ssoId.awsapps.com/start\nRegion: $AWS_REGION\nUsername: amplify-admin\n\n"

this has to be given proper privileges this can be found: IAM user access permission

I had an AWS account visible when logging in the Identity Center portal on the web access, but not in the CLI, and had the same message.
Waiting 15 min was just it for me. I just logged again after watching tutorials, and it just worked.
